# Android playing video with the camera surfaceview in background

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview

Hello
i have a surfaceview and a videview in a framlayout. if i start the video in oncreate, i see all perfectly, the video playing while the camera plays in background.
but if i start the video after oncreate, for example in onpreviewframe, i can only hear the video, but it's like behind the camera, and all i see is the camera view.

any help?

Comment: i think it would be better if you could post your source code and log

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Merge both layouts... see the [Example](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html).